# How to use the Select2 jQuery plugin with html select control in asp.net web forms?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

I am trying to use Select2 jquery plugin with html  element in my aspx page. Select2 does not seem like working. I have attached the picture. I have those options populated twice in my UI. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

[image]

```
   my aspx page:

   <div style="padding: 3px;">                      
   <select id="SelectCountry" name="country" runat="server" class="js-example-basic-single" 
    multiple="true" clientidmode="Static"></select>
    </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"  
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
            placeholder: "Select an option",
           
            data: [{
                'text': 'Finland',
                'children': [{
                    'id': 1,
                    'text': 'India'
                },
                {
                    'id': 2,
                    'text': 'Australia'
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                'text': 'America',
                'children': [{
                    'id': 3,
                    'text': 'Cali'
                },
                {
                    'id': 4,
                    'text': 'NY'
                }
                ]
            },
            ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: what is your html code showing?

Comment: @Mech, Please take a look at my html code. Could not copy it so attached it in a question.

Comment: Note that select2 script has to be called after jquery has loaded. It also needs CSS to display properly so you should also include it's default css

Comment: @Tavershima I was missing including its default CSS.Works now. Thank you.